# How to set hint text to Pinput in flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, hint

I use pinput on my app , and I should set hint text on it , but there is no hint text and hint text style arguments on pinput.

I tried sms_auto_fill lib , but this lib doesnt support custom width and height , so i decide to use pinput lib , but this lib doesnt have hint text and hint style arguments

Comment: If you want to use same text in every box in pinput. You can use ->   Pinput(
        length: 6,
        onCompleted: (value) {        },
        preFilledWidget: Text('*'),
      ), -------> or you can use https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields it supports hint style and hint text.